# Export the scale_x and scale_y values displayed in the xyplot of the lattice package

Tags: r, lattice

Is there some way to export the scale_x and scale_y values displayed in the xyplot of the lattice package? I run for example the following code but no name seems to contain these values.

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

myplot <- xyplot(cars$speed~cars$dist)
print(myplot) 
# xx': 0, 20, ..., 120
# yy': 5, 10, ..., 25

str(myplot)
```

Thank in advance all of you.

Comment: you want to export the scale_x values displayed in the plot?

Comment: yes, indeed, but names does not return them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that plotting scenario, you can extract the `x` ticks with

```
myplot$xscale.components(lim = myplot$x.limits)$bottom$ticks$at
```

and `y` ticks with

```
myplot$yscale.components(lim = myplot$y.limits)$left$ticks$at
```

You can find more complete versions of these calls in the `lattice:::plot.trellis` function